# Сравнение строк из базы данных с переменной (SQLite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Подскажите пожалуйста, пишу приложение на андроид и есть необходимость вытащить строку с определённым строковым значением которое задано в переменной как можно это реализовать?
P.S.Я пробовал разными способами но как то не получается ниже представлен код

```
 for (String s:this.spisokKontaktov.keySet()){
                    Cursor cur=database.rawQuery("SELECT "+KEY_phone+" as _id"+" from "+TABLE_CONTACTS+" where _id= "+s,new String[]{});
                boolean k=cur.moveToFirst();
```

P.S.S. s -переменная с которой сравниваю

Comment: Зачем в запросе `as _id`? что что значит `_id`?

Comment: Я думаю следующий запрос был бы более правильным: `Cursor cur = database.rawQuery("SELECT "+KEY_phone+" FROM "+TABLE_CONTACTS+" WHERE _id = ?", new String[] {s});` Если вы уверены,что вам нужна выборка именно по _id

Comment: у меня в программе вытаскивается номера телефонов из телефонной книги.....и поэтому я создал базу данных с индификатором по номеру телефона и мне надо сравнить наличие номера телефона в базе если нет то добавить запись в базу данных

Comment: номера телефонов в качестве идентификатора не лучшее решение, так как они вполне могут быть не уникальны. лучше сделать отдельное поле с номером и искать по нему, а колонку _id сделать как положено - integer autoincrement

Comment: так а как сравнить значение номера из бд с переменной?

Comment: Cursor cur=database.rawQuery("SELECT "+KEY_phone+" as phone"+" from "+TABLE_CONTACTS+" where phone= ?",new String[]{s});
показывает ошибку на вопросе

Comment: как называется таблица в БД в которой у вас находятся номера?

Comment: public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS ="Phone_Key";

Comment: и как колонка с номерами в этой таблице называется тоже напишите

Comment: public static final String KEY_phone="phone";

Comment: `Cursor cur = database.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {"_id", KEY_phone}, KEY_phone + " = ?", new String[] {s}, null, null, null);` - лучше использовать метод `query()`, а не сырой запрос `rawQuery()` это безопаснее.

Comment: ваша проблема решилась?